# Div with height is 0px, it does not grow in relation to their children

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I have the div `div.home-top` with two other divs `div#home-content` as `float:left` and `div#home-buttons` as `float:right`.

And below the `div#home-top` got the `div#home-footer` as `clear:both`

My `div#home-top` is the minimum size.
I put it in red, but I can not see it.
How to make the `div#home-top` take on the height divs children.
[See](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/5jJg3/13/) the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the CSS for `div#home-top`:

```
div#home-top
{
    background-color:Red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5jJg3/14/)

Answer (score 2):

Floated divs have no height, so .home-top does not expand. You will need to give it an explicit height or unfloat the inner elements.